# Linux kill process by cmdline (multiple with same name)

Tags: bash, mono, kill

I am writing a bash-file (.command @OS X) to easily update a program at my remote server (Linux). I am stuck trying to figure out which PID to kill. I have different processes with the same name, which is **mono**, since they are executed by mono.

Using **pgrep mono** I get all the PIDs using mono, however, I only want to kill the process that has the command line **SCREEN -dmSL steambot mono SteamBot.exe**.

How do I know what PID to kill? Atm, my .command file looks like this:

```
ssh xxx@xxxx.com
pgrep mono
```

I am using ssh-keychain to login also.

Comment: since you know exactly what you want, you should grep for that, rather than the mono line, and then use cut to get the PID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

```
ps -ef | grep '[S]CREEN -dmSL steambot mono SteamBot\.exe' |
  awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill
```